# if {} elseif {} else for final comparison

Tags: powershell, if-statement

Qns: i need some advice as to how to use the if else if else condition comparision before output to a .csv file.

```
if $_.sideIndicator -eq "=>" output to test.csv 
else if $_.sideIndicator -eq "<=" output to test.csv
else echo "there is no changes" output to test.csv
```

current code is:

```
clear-host
$northdb = Import-Csv "C:\temp\cep\Book1.csv" -Header "InstanceName", "DatabaseName" | Sort-object -Property "InstanceName", "DatabaseName" -Unique 
$sdb = Import-Csv "C:\temp\cep\Book2.csv" -Header "InstanceName", "DatabaseName"  |Sort-Object -Property "InstanceName", "DatabaseName" -Unique
Compare-Object $northdb $sdb -Property  "InstanceName", "DatabaseName" -PassThru |  Where-Object{$_.SideIndicator -eq '=>'} | Select-Object  "InstanceName", "DatabaseName" | export-csv C:\temp\cep\gogo.csv -NoTypeInfo
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to put all the changed items into test.csv but if the two CSVs are identical then you want to output "there are no changes"?

Comment: You example shows you outputting the data to the same file regardless. The only exception is if there is not data? Do you really need that text in the output file? Is the lack of data good enough?

Comment: When working with external data it's always good to have some sort of output. If the output of the script itself is not monitored you need to know if the task succeeded, if there is a lack of output you can then assume there was an error or it didn't run.

Comment: @Deadly-Bagel That depends on the use of the output. Some other system might not like that text. That is generally only useful to humans. Still worth asking. Could easily display that text in console as well.

Comment: Hi Deadly-Bagel, what i need to achieve is i need to compare the difference between this 2 .csv files. Basically is Book1.csv vs Book2.csv. I need to catch if there is additional infor that exist in Book2 then output the diff to another file. And if there exist any infor in Book1 that is not in Book2 it will output the result. else other things, output as no changes.

Comment: hi matt, .....regarding replying to your qns, ..."You example shows you outputting the data to the same file regardless. The only exception is if there is not data? Do you really need that text in the output file? Is the lack of data good enough? – Matt...." >> i should say they need not write to the same output. scenario 1 can output as "somethingAddedInbook2.csv. scenario 2 can output to somethingInBook1andNotInbook2.csv. Scenario 3 is nochanges.csv

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this:

```
if ($_.sideIndicator -eq "=>")
    {$Something| export-csv "C:\csvPath"}
elseif ($_.sideIndicator -eq "<=")
    {$Something| export-csv "C:\csvPath"}
else
    {Write-Output "there is no changes"}
```

Comment: This isn't a full response, if you pipe the results of Compare-Object then it will never see anything other than => or <= so doesn't work. First he needs to be more specific about what he's asking for.